# Making a toggle button in react with jquery not working

Tags: jquery, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I've been running into a problem with my react web application. In want to make a voting system where if you hit the like button it changes color and it can only be liked once. If you hit it again it goes back to 'neutral' and the like count gets decremented. Same goes for the dislike button. If you have something liked and you hit the dislike, for example, the the like goes back to eutral and the dislike changes color. Basically like the YouTube video like system. Im running into this problem, though, with my method:

```
const[score,setScore] = useState(0);
    const[dislike,setDislike] = useState(0);
    const[buttonState,setButtonState] = useState(true);
    var boolD = true;
    var boolL = true;
    const incrmentLike = () => {
        setScore(idea.score +=1)
        console.log(idea.score)

    }

    var disliked = false;
const incrmentDislike = () => {
        setDislike(idea.dislike +=1)
}
var flag = 0;
    function toggleDislike(){
    if(flag===0){
        console.log(flag)
        flag=1;
        incrmentDislike()
        console.log(flag)
        disliked = true;
    }
    else if(flag===1){
        setDislike(idea.dislike -=1)
        disliked = false;
        flag=0;
        console.log(flag)
    }
    
    }


return(
    <div className="idea-details">
        {isPending && <div>Leading...</div>}
        {idea && (
            <article>
                <h2>{idea.ideaTitle}</h2>
                <p>Written by {idea.author}</p>
                <div>{idea.body} </div>
                <div>{idea.score} Likes {idea.dislike} Dislikes</div>
            </article>
        )}
        <a type="button" className={classNameLU} id="button2" title="button" onClick={() => incrmentLike()}>Like!</a>
        <div
            className="btn btn-warning btn-lg"
            style={{ backgroundColor: dislike ? "#35b5f1" : "#8b8b8b" }}
            id="toggleDiv"
            onClick={toggleDislike}
            >
            Dislike
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

}
Basically The flag always gets reset to 0 and the method never gets to the if statement where the flag == 1. I think its because useState() is reseting the variable somehow. I was wondering if I could get help to get around this? I'm only working on the dislike button right now. setScore is the like button. You can ignore the first button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React and jquery don't generally mix. The issue is that jquery directly manipulates the DOM outside the React component lifecycle so React isn't triggered to rerender the UI. Additionally, yes, `flag` is reset to `0` each render cycle, it's not held in any state or React ref so it's value isn't saved from render to render. Stick to using React state to persist values from render to render.

Move the background color to a `style` prop and use the dislike state to conditionally set one background color or the other.

```
<div
  className="btn btn-warning btn-lg"
  style={{ backgroundColor: disliked ? "#35b5f1" : "#8b8b8b" }}
  id="toggleDiv"
  onClick={toggleDislike}
>
  Dislike
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I figured, jquery didn't fit well at all, it was hard to get it to work at first thanks for the advice, this way of changing colors is much better, I will update my code. Do you have any advice for getting around flag always resetting?

Comment: @AndrewViera Re: `flag` (*and others*) always resetting, don't declare it/them in the function body, make it/them part of component state, or use a React ref to store the value(s) so it/they persist(s) through rerenders.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense lol, I just moved the variables above the function and it works properly now. Thank you!

Comment: So as a general rule, should I NEVER use jquery with react?

Comment: @AndrewViera Yeah, for the most part. The reason being is they have rather orthogonal approaches to handling UI updates, and all the useful aspects of jquery for grabbing DOM elements can be handled in React using refs.